# Adjusting database(MySQL) data with vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to make a function that adjust data in a MySQL-database with vb.net.

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub alterDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles alterDB.Click
    Dim user As String = globalValue.userN
    Dim password As String = globalValue.passwN
    If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
        Dim newValue As Integer
        newValue = Label3.Text - NumericUpDown1.Value

        Dim conn As New sqlConnection   
        Dim answerN As DataTable        
        Dim sqlQnA As String = "INSERT INTO equiptment(inStorage) value '" & newValue & "' WHERE iName='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

            conn.altering(user, password, sqlQnA)
            answerN = conn.getData()

    End If

End Sub
```

The error message I get suggest it's almost functioning, just not entirely :)

> Error msg: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "140' WHERE iNavn='SkateboardW15" at line 1.

Comment: INSERTs dont use WHERE clauses; INSERT adds a row.  YOu probably want UPDATE which will "adjust" a row. `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version` == good advice

Comment: Ah, figured it was just some minor problem, for some reason I was fixated on INSERT, when UPDATE was the right way to go. Now it's working well, thank you :)!

Comment: Don't include your data in sql strings like that. It leaves your app crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Use query parameters instead.

Comment: you do have to fix the connection string (below)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'm just trying to educate myself at this point (just running on a closed local server), but any advices are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an **UPDATE** instead of an INSERT. Also, you should look into parameterized queries, to avoid sql injection attacks. What you have is crazy vulnerable. It looks like you're using a custom type to manage your connection and execute queries. That's fine, but you need to add support to that type for query parameters. It also worth mentioning that ADO.Net relies on a connection pooling feature, such that it works best when you use a new SqlConnection object for most queries.

```vb
Private Sub alterDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles alterDB.Click
    'Move password enforcement to your connection object or connection string

    'use a guard clause that does not increase the nesting depth of your code
    If string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ComboBox1.Text) Then Exit Sub

    Dim newValue As Integer = CInt(Label3.Text) - NumericUpDown1.Value    
    'sql string should be a constant, or any changes should only be typed by the programmer
    '                                 never the user
    Dim sqlQnA As String = "UPDATE equipment SET inStorage = @newValue WHERE iName= @iName"

    'Using block will guarantee the connection is closed properly, even if an exception is thrown
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlQnA, conn)

        'use query parameters that allow you to set the specific database type and length you need
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@iName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = ComboBox1.Text

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonquery()
    End Using 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for or at least I hope it points you into the right direction:

```
Private Sub alterDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles alterDB.Click
   If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
      Dim con As New SqlConnection
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

      Try
         ' Change Everything In The Next Line With CAPS To Your Configuration '
         con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;User ID=" & globalValue.userN & ";Password=" & globalValue.passwN

         con.Open()

         cmd.Connection = con
         cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO equiptment(inStorage) value '" & newValue & "' WHERE iName='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", con)
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

      Catch ex AS Exception
         ' Do Something If Error Exist '
      Finally
         con.close()
      End Try
   End If
End Sub
```